# Can not load module when run Unit testcase

Tags: swift

I am building a framework(**`Provider`**), In this framework, I used library(**`sdk.a`**).
This library is written in Objective C. My framework is in Swift so I used `modulemap`.
In the `modulemap` I name the library SDK

In code I used

```
import SDK //this line issue error when run unit testcase
class Manager{
    public static let shared = Manager()
    private var agent: LocalAgent? //SDK class
    public connect: Bool
    //no issue it works fine
     private func find(_ device: Device) {
        //more logical codes
        self.connect = true
    } 
}
```

Above code works fine when I build the framework or use the framework form another application.

Problem is when I run `testConnect()`from unit test case file,
Compiler issue error in Manager.swift files `import SDK` statement **"No such module 'SDK'"**

Test case file: ManagerTest.swift

```
@testable import SDK
@testable import Provider
func testConnect(){
    let manager = Manager.shared
    manager.find(device)
}
```

Comment: Are you facing the issue for framework testcase or for App testcase?

Comment: I am facing the problem in framework testcase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `SDK.a` target membership for `ProviderTests` target. Like,

1. Select `SDK.a` file
2. Add tick the tests target membership for that file
3. Then clean build and run the tests again.

[image]

Image attribution: [Medium post](https://medium.com/@andersongusmao/xcode-targets-with-multiples-build-configuration-90a575ddc687)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but in my case it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of this problem is

1. Do not add `Manager.Swift` file in `ProviderTests` target membership
2. add `@testable import Provider` line in `ManagerTest.swift` file